# Displaying Text with SDL_ttf without font file hard code

Tags: c, ubuntu, fonts, render, sdl-ttf

I have code in **C LANGUAGE** to display text on screen using SDL_ttf library in linux.

```
TTF_Font *font;
      font = TTF_OpenFont("FreeSans.ttf", 20);
```

But in this I don't want to give file name as hard coded or file path. so when I execute this programme on other Linux machine it should run fine. I don't want to keep always this font file with my executable.

Is there any way to write portable code  for `TTF_OpenFont` ?
or i can use something else that can solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid hardcoding fonts you need to integrate `SDL_TTF` with fontconfig.

Or use fontconfig through a higher-level framework like [Pango](http://sdlpango.sourceforge.net/).